# Rails wice_grid with virtual class attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, wice-grid

I need to show a virtual attribute :status in my wicegrid but I always get the error that :status is not in the database .... of course its not, its virtual !

**Is there a way to have a column containing a virtual attribute? and if Yes, how can I have a custom filter on that?**

the model

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :status
end
```

in the view

```
<%= grid(@grid, upper_pagination_panel: false) do |g|
    g.column name: "Status", attribute: "status"
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation from Wice Grid says that it is not possible to use a virtual attribute for a column...

> It is important to remember that :attribute is the name of the database column, not a model attribute. Of course, all database columns have corresponding model attributes, but not all model attributes map to columns in the same table with the same name.

Sorry i cannot help anymore, maybe someone else will answer the other half of the question.